# Is there any way to use Spring MVC 3.1 (particullary, RedirectAttributes) with Spring 3.0.5?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

It's so frustating, but I cannot upgrade Spring core to 3.1, only MVC. 
The thing is that I need to use Flash Attributes after a redirect.
Or maybe there's a "howto" to do the same as RedirectAttributes, in Spring 3.0.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement it yourself.

For the flash request attributes, add them to the session with a special flag attribute (a prefix in their string key value), like `REDIRECT_HAPPENING_<attributeName>`.

Then create an interceptor that checks if you have any attributes named that way in the session. If you do, add them as request attributes (and remove them from the session - you can do this in `postHandle()`), otherwise return.